# Как переключить класс у li, если nuxt-link активна?

Tags: nuxt.js

**Здравствуйте, коллеги!**

Есть список:

```
<ul id="app">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
    <NLink to="/page" exact active-class="active-link">Link {{ index }}</NLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

При заходе на роут `/page` - класс `active-link` присваивается к , а мне **нужно чтобы класс присваивался к `<li>`**. Как это сделать в **nuxt.js** ?

Я искал информацию по этому поводу, но единственное предложение которое я встретил - это через `v-slot`, но это решение не желательно в проекте.

Может кто-то сталкивался и решал уже эту проблему ?

**Буду благодарен любой помощи!**

Answer (score 1):

Я знаю только один способ: сравнивать ссылку `to` в `<li>` с текущим значением `$nuxt.$route.path` или `$nuxt.$route.name`